# Storing Data from Redux Store in Another Data Structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, lodash, redux

My app loads data from Firebase into a Redux store on-load. It loads as an object containing a few hundred nested objects.

In order to render a table component (specifically, [this one](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/index.html)) for that data, I have to convert it into an array of objects.

My current solution is to simply convert it within the table component `mapStateToProps()` like this (using the `lodash` library):

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        listingsData: _.values(state.config)
    }
}
```

This appears to work, and changes I make in the Firebase dashboard successfully render in my app almost instantly.

My question is: does this way of doing things result in 2x the memory consumption for my app (the array + the store)?

This isn't a problem with a few hundred rows, but I expect some users to have several thousand rows of data.

If it IS 2x memory, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

ETA: I think this answer might still be helpful in the future, but in retrospect I should've just written a little test.  The accepted answer below is supported by this test:

```
var x = {a:{var:1}, b:{var:2}, c:{var:3}};
var y = _.values(x);

console.log(x, y); //values match

x.a.var = 99;

console.log(x, y); //values still match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I understand _.values function from loadash (haven't work with loadash), in your case you are not doubling your memory (cloning objects), but creating array of references to those objects you have in store which is all right.

What you may want to consider is filtering those objects before referencing rather then always creating reference to every object.

Comment: thanks - can you expand on your filtering point? is referencing every obj sub-optimal, performance-wise?  

i will eventually include a filter using user-defined parameters, and I had intended to put that in mapStateToProps -- is that what you mean?

Comment: If you have params over which you filter data (in state maybe or something static) you could filter state before passing it to component. This is more arhitectural question then performance in general, but in your case, question is do you need reference to every object or only some? Will you use every object? If not, you could create list of object with only those you need.

Comment: that makes sense.  the data is basically a list of the user's records, so the current intended ux is that the user sees all records in tabular form on-load, then can apply filters as-needed. if i understand you correctly, if i determine later that the user is only interested in some subset of their records on first load, i think your method of filtering before passing to component sounds like it'd be optimal.